# MySQL query PHP "sorry...query failed, please click me" ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, using

I worked on an Marketplace php script and every time when i want login to an User Account I get only this Error: sorry...query failed, please click me home

```
query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($useroremail) . "' and `password`='" . md5($password) . "' and `userlevel`='".($vendor==true ? 30 : 20)."'LIMIT 1;") or die('sorry...query failed, please click me <a href="./index.php">home</a>');     $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
        if($row_cnt==1){
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if ($vendor==true){
        setcookie('lite_engine', $gbhgbhgbh->encrypt('['.(time()+86400).';'.$row['username'] . ']2','/'),  time()+86400);
        }else{
        setcookie('lite_engine', $gbhgbhgbh->encrypt('['.(time()+86400).';'.$row['username'] . ']1','/'),  time()+86400);
        }
```

I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: post full sql syntax; result this: echo "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($useroremail) . "' and `password`='" . md5($password) . "' and `userlevel`='".($vendor==true ? 30 : 20)."'LIMIT 1;";

Comment: Don't output `sorry error`; output the actual error message, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0):

To see what is wrong with your query try debugging it Here's how I debug query's

1. echo the query to the screen
2. copy the printed query from the screen
3. execute the query in you db manager (phpmyadmin)
4. Read the sql error (here you will see what's wrong with the query) and
5. change your query accordingly

   ```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($useroremail) . "' and `password`='" . md5($password) . "' and `userlevel`='".($vendor==true ? 30 : 20)."'LIMIT 1;";
   echo $query;
   ```